# How to support window.print() in a embedded web browser using JavaFx java 1.7

Tags: java, javafx, embedded-browser

I have created an embedded browser **using jdk1.7 (and bundled javafx with jdk 7).**
However a button on html page having `onClick="window.print()"` **is not working**.

Any idea how can this be fix.

Thanks and Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you note in your question, Java 7 will not work for printing WebView content as it lacks the required functionality to do so.

Try Java 8, it adds printing support, though I don't know if printing of WebView content is supported when triggered through JavaScript.

Comment: will WebEngine.executeScript("window.print()"); work ? if somehow i can capture the window.print event in my embedded browser.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it won't work in Java 7 and I don't know if it will work in Java 8, try it and you can post the definitive answer yourself.

Comment: I just tried, .executeScript("window.print()"); it doesn't work. You are right.